# Linkage between reality and perception

Tags: meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis, sentence-meaning

I am trying to make sense of this statement:

> So in common parlance reality still means reality, but includes the 
>   assumption that perception is an accurate indicator of reality, 
>   a known falsehood and actually conceded by everyone.

What does it mean to say, "reality still means reality"?  How can 'reality' be a 'known falsehood'?  What exactly is 'conceded by everyone'?  What do you think this sentence really means?

Note that this is a question about *grammar*, not philosophy.

Comment: The "known falsehood" is the clause ending right before _a known falsehood_. I.e, it is known to be true that perception is ***not*** an accurate indicator of reality -- what we perceive is generated by reality, but it does not represent most of reality, only the transforms we are built to receive and identify. And it does not perceive, but rather guesses at, social, personal, and emotional "realities", especially not those perceived by other people.

Comment: While the critical reading skills necessary to understand that sentence belong here, the discussion that follows belongs here: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/  This is a fun place to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualia

Comment: Where did this quote come from?  It's so badly written....

Comment: This is not a philosophical question; it is a question of grammar.  How should it be punctuated to make the antecedent to 'a known falsehood' clear?

Answer (score 2):

The author is saying that we have to assume, for the sake of daily life, that the reality we perceive is in fact reality. We could be living in a simulation, and the world could very well be a dream, but if you go around assuming that whenever something happens it may not actually happen it makes life difficult for everyone. If someone goes around making the statement that the world may not be real thinking he is an insightful philosopher, no one would take them seriously. We all know that the world may not be the real world and that perception isn't a perfect system (hence known falsehood) but unless we get together and work in *our world* nothing could be accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little opaque, but let's break down the phrases.

> reality still means reality

In the minds of most individuals, their perception of reality is indeed reality.

> the assumption that perception is an accurate indicator of reality

Consider the first [optical illusion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_illusion) of the Wikipedia entry, namely that of the checker shadow.
[image: Checker shadow illusion]

Your perception is that square A and B are different shades of gray, but this is not reality. They are in fact the same shade (although you may have to download the image and sample A and B with an image editor to convince yourself.)

The author is saying that the assumption that our perceptions are correct is

> a known falsehood

(Note that it is the *assumption that our perceptions are correct* that is *a known falsehood*, not the OP's interpretation that *reality* is *a known falsehood*.)

Our assumptions are incorrect because our perceptions can be fooled, as in the cited optical illusion.

The author asserts that the knowledge of this falsehood is

> actually conceded by everyone.

(I disagree that *everyone* concedes this falsehood. Many children or those from other cultures would trust their eyes and their perceptions and may not perceive an illusion. Please read more at [Müller-Lyer illusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCller-Lyer_illusion), especially at "natives of the Australian Murray Island were less susceptible to the Müller-Lyer illusion.")

Comment: Should it be punctuated differently?  How did you know that reality is not a known falsehood?

Comment: I might have broken it into several sentences. The author is not asserting that reality is a known falsehood; rather, that perception is a known falsehood. Look at the phrase "that perception is an accurate indicator of reality, a known falsehood."